# 301 redirect unique url

Tags: php, html, redirect, http-redirect

I am looking for away to redirect urls that have a unique job key at the end below are a few examples:

`http://domain-name/jf-jobkey&t=zz237933-6561-f56y-8huh-78654&` redirects to `http://newdomain.com/jobkey=zz237933-6561-f56y-8huh-78654&`

`http://domain-name/jf-jobkey&t=a5956783-r567-k980-9jko-45678&` redirects to `http://newdomain.com/jobkey=a5956783-r567-k980-9jko-45678&`

The issue is emails have been sent with the old url and don't have a way to see what jobkeys to make an easy 301 redirect.

```
<?php
 function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  } else {
 $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

Here is some code I can catch the url but how could i just pull out the jockey? everything after the =

Comment: The are different approach to solve this issue. First, How many urls do you have to redirect?

Comment: there are over 400. I was hoping on doing maybe a url catch then part out the jockey? and place in the new redirect

Comment: You can use PHP $_SERVER variable to get the url and then redirects using header(), you can use rewrite engine of apache